# The simplest way to delete a section of text, n times

Tags: bash, shell, vi

I have a file bigger than 4gb which is bad news for me because I can't open the file in notepad++ and use the macro feature to record and repeat a process to the end of a file.
What I'd like to do is say, leave the first 20 lines of text, then delete the next 80, then repeat that process to the end of a file.

What would be the easiest way to do this?
I'm looking at these files on a linux server so running a script of some kind would be the easiest way, or maybe someone knows a way to do this in vi? (hence the lame taging)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`awk` can do this fairly easily:

```
awk '(NR-1)%100 < 20' bigfile.txt
```

Comment: why you came up first with (NR-1)%100<20 but not NR%100<=20. :)  +1 nice solution!

Comment: @Kent Consider row 100. We want to remove it, but `NR%100 <= 20` would keep it.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy post! How would I save all that so it prints it to a new file?

Comment: Add a shell redirect to the end: `awk '(NR-1)%100 < 20' bigfile.txt >shorter.txt`

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the awk solution, but here's one way you could do the same thing with sed:

```
seq 20 | sed 's/$/~100p/' | sed -nf - bigfile.txt
```

Testing:

```
seq 20 | sed 's/$/~100p/' | sed -nf - <(seq 200)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
```

Comment: I didn't test, just want to know, what would be the output order of this line? would it be `#1,#101,#201,#301....#2,#102,#202.... #20,#120,#220..` ?